# bug on scroll down sections in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is `javascript` code for scrolling down the sections :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function() {
$('.nav').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($('#' + id + '.section').offset().top)
    }, 1000);
});
       })();
</script>
```

I have 3 sections in this page and every section has different background color :

```
    <div class="section" id="1" style="background-color:#0F0">
<section>

</section>
</div>
<div class="section" id="2" style="background-color:#0FF">
<section>

</section>
</div>
<div class="section" id="3" style="background-color:#CF6">
<section>

</section>
</div>
```

It works great, but it has a bug. Sometimes when I scrolling with that `javascript` code it shows the section 1 in like 500 milliseconds then go to the other section.

**Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/95xnjzLs/)**

How can I fix that for not showing section 1 when I don't need it.

It's better on `firefox` than `chrome` or `IE`. I mean sometimes it happen on `firefox` but always happen on other browsers.

It's something like bug how can I fix it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you give us jsfiddle link

Comment: @Dileep See the update. I mentioned that.

Comment: I'd recommend you to use [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) plugin if your sections are the size of the viewport. Take a look at this example: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your HTML links just replace href with the hash tag of the relevant div.

```js
$(function() {
$('.nav').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($('#' + id + '.section').offset().top)
    }, 1000);
});
       })();
```

```css
nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
 font-size:18px;
 font-family:"B Koodak";
}

a {
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.section {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <a class="nav" id="1" href="#1">A</a>
    <a class="nav" id="2" href="#2">B</a>
    <a class="nav" id="3" href="#3">C</a>
</nav>
<div class="section" id="1" style="background-color:#0F0">
<section>
<p>hi</p>
</section>
</div>
<div class="section" id="2" style="background-color:#0FF">
<section>
<p>how are you</p>
</section>
</div>
<div class="section" id="3" style="background-color:#CF6">
<section>
<p>welcome</p>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Or you can add onclick event handler to all anchor tags. like this
<a class="nav" id="1" href="#" onclick="return false">A</a>